# wrong number of template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, mergesort

I want to write template Merge Sort.

```
    template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Comparator = std::less<>>
void MergeSort(RandomAccessIterator begin, RandomAccessIterator end, Comparator compare) {
    int s = end - begin;
    if (s > 1)
    {
        RandomAccessIterator middle = begin + s / 2 + 1;
        MergeSort(begin, middle, compare);
        MergeSort(middle, end, compare);
        std::inplace_merge(begin, middle, end, compare);
    }
}
```

And the message I get is:  error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1)
 template >.

I tried to move std::less to function declaration, but also failed. What do I need to do?

Comment: `std::less<T>` needs a type for `T`, it cannot be empty.  Perhaps you could use something like `std::less<std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type>`.

Comment: @HenriMenke it can since C++14. They are called diamond operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged your question as `C++11`, it seem you cannot use diamond operators.

As you can see in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), the form `std::less<>` is only allowed since `C++14`.

What you can do here is to use the other form:

```
std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type>
```